# Protein supplement recommendation based on diet

Tags: weightlifting, diet, bodybuilding, supplements

I am body building along with 1 day cardio but i think that i am not taking enough protein in a day. So this is what my diet is :

**Preworkout** : Milk or sometimes oats with milk

**After workout** : 1 Coconut

**Breakfast :** 2/3 Whole grain bread with peanut butter

**Lunch :** 3 Chapati(Made from wheat).

**Dinner :** 6 boil eggs(only white part).Sometimes i miss this.

**Milk :** 1 Glass before sleep.

So here i don't think i am getting enough protein in my body because of which i am not seeing that result which i want to see.I don't want to have bulky body.I want to have kind of aesthetic body.

This is the reason why i am thinking for protein supplements because as you can see i am not getting enough protein after my workout which is very important as far as i know.

I am thinking for **1 up Isolate** or may be **nitro tech** but not sure which will be good.

Weight : 79 kg
Height : 5`9 (180 cm)

Can anybody please recommend me what would be a better choice?

Comment: based on what you described here I think you eating less than you need to build up your muscles. I mean coconut, bread with penuat butter, 3 chapati -looks like carbs mostly. How much is your weight? How many calories you consume per day?

Comment: As example, my weight is 75 kilos, and my breakfast is like 200-300 grams of boiled chiken breast with oats/noodles around 100-200 grams. Same for lunch and dinner, I'd say. Before sleep I got some crud around 250 grams.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman My Weight is i guess 79 kg and height is 5`9 but i dont count amount of calories that i consume in a day.Can you please recommend me something please

Comment: Based on your weight and height (also, age matters, but I assumed you in your 20s) you need to consume around 2500 - 3000 kcal per day and, whats most important, it suppose to be healthy meal (I mean, no calories from sugar and other sweet stuff, white bread, sweet fruits etc) - rich with protein (so, mostly meat, fish (better not fried, also there is some good fats in it), eggs, crud), also 'slow-carbs' - like buckwheat, oat porriges etc, some bread is fine but only dark types.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Sorry but my age is 27 and what about protein supplement recommendation.Do you thin supplements are worth taking?

Comment: Well,if you will get enough protein from food (120-160 grams per day) I dont think you need'em. I mean, protein from food and protein powder is almost same thing (but it could be different amount of aminoacids, in protein from fish/meat/milk-related (idk hows it in english, you know cheese, crud, stuff made from milk) products count of types of aminoacids it contains same/almsot same as in those cans with powder)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman
Yeah i do understand but the problem is i dont regularly take all this food like meat,chicken etc.I miss alot that is why i was thinking for the supplement

Comment: Well, then regular whey protein will fit in, I guess, by any popular sport nutrition will be fine (ON, Olymp, BSN) But better to combine, deal with this powder protein mixes could be hard for your stomach, I'd say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68691/discussion-between-learning-and-danil-gholtsman).

Comment: I personally like to avoid supplements. I am not even body building anyway. But even I try to make sure I got around 140 g of protein daily. Add 200g of canned salmon to your diet. It contains 50g of proteins and might be almost cost effective compared to protein shakes. You also obtain large portion of your fat from a single source. I honestly did not look at essential fatty acid distribution of coconut, but if you are not absolutely sure it contains everything, eat cashew, walnut, almond etc for the same amount of calories in one or two days a week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me put some primary points out that anyone doing resistance training needs to understand.

**Programming**

You need to follow an effective training program. Not some lifts you think are the right ones, not something out of a magazine. [There are very well known strength training programs out there with solid track records](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091): follow them. Understand where you are on [internationally recognized strength standards](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.htm), and aim to get to the intermediate level in all areas.

**Diet**

Directly answering your question, you should eat north of 260 grams of protein per day. This has been well studied, and most people advocating for more than 3.3g/kg are trying to sell you supplements. From [Lyle McDonald](https://www.bodyrecomposition.com/muscle-gain/protein-requirements-for-strength-and-power-athletes.html/):

> ... strength/power athletes should aim for 1.5 g/lb protein per day
>   (again, this is about 3.3 g/kg for the metrically inclined).

Personally, I shoot for 2.1 g/kg because I can accomplish that without severely altering my diet and don't have to eat chicken and whey seven times a day. The diet of a high level body builder is *very* different than what normal people eat. Planning, structuring, and preparing your meals is something that takes a lot of time, every day.

Ultimately I feel that a "pretty good" diet that you can actually stick with is better than the "perfect" diet which you can't effectively maintain.

**Be Patient**

There really are no shortcuts to physical fitness. Our bodies take a while to respond, and it is the steady, consistent, and regular effort that wins. Give yourself at least six months to see any changes in the mirror, and two years is a reasonable time for people to honestly not recognize you anymore. Again, that's two years of steadily following the right diet and following an effective program.

**Protein Supplementation**

Eating real food is much better than supplements. Your body needs fiber, fats, minerals, and nutrients that are not found in protein supplements.

1. [Find out the total amount of calories you need via a calculator](http://www.calculator.net/calorie-calculator.html). It's not going to be exact, but it will be close, and much closer than you guessing.
2. [Figure out your macronutrients also using a calculator](http://macronutrientcalculator.com/).
3. [Start tracking your calories and macros](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/). You know what you need (calories and macros) and now you can see what you're actually putting in. You should do this for at least a week, and anytime you can't honestly tell yourself down to the ~100 calorie mark how much you've had that day.
4. Adjust your diet until you are meeting your macros and calories.

If this seems like a ton of work, you can start to see why everyone isn't walking around with 5% body fat and squatting 315lb.

But what you will probably find is that it is logistically tough and expensive to eat such a large amount of protein. Fats and carbs are cheap and easy to come by but protein is rare and expensive. This is the reason that people supplement with products like whey. [Some proteins (like red meat) eaten on the regular have their own health problems as well.](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/cutting-red-meat-for-a-longer-life)

Adjust your real-food diet as much as you can to target your macros. If and when you fall short, do exactly what the name implies: supplement.

Whey protein in particular is [cheap](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/25430/7091), [safe](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements-whey-protein/art-20363344), and easy to prepare. A caveat to any supplementation (including whey) is consider the other ingredients as well. I personally have switched to [the "natural" whey products](https://www.optimumnutrition.com/en_US/products/naturally-flavored-whey) without artificial sweeteners, because of the [recently discussed link between those artificial sweeteners and dementia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28428346).

Especially if you're going to be taking a scoop or two of some product every day for years on end, you really want to know the safety of what you're consuming.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer and you explained beautifully.The problem with me is sometimes i just miss my diet and because of that i suffer from calorie deficit diet.That is why i was thinking for supplements but i know supplements should never be an option over food but because of my diet i have to take supplements now.I was thinking for  https://www.myprotein.co.in/sports-nutrition/impact-whey-isolate/10530911.html.What is your view on this?

Comment: Oh my, "link between those artificial sweeteners and dementia". I'm 25 soon, so I should quit on zero coke? :(

Comment: Or not? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/behindtheheadlines/news/2017-04-21-reported-link-between-diet-drinks-and-dementia-and-stroke-is-weak/

Comment: That's a syndicated oped piece with no author, not a peer reviewed study. And as I said, it was my personal choice but regardless folks should understand ingredients and make their decisions.

Comment: @Learning most of those myprotein whey products have sucralose as a sweetener, which again you should check the research on and make your opinion. But in general yes, I think you're looking at it correctly. A big part of fitness is diet and consider taking some time to crank up your cooking skills if you haven't already. I learned how to put frozen chicken breasts into an Instant Pot and 10 minutes later they're perfect (as an example). So don't consider your current food prep skills as the end of the line, they can get much better and nothing complex needed.

Comment: @Eric Kaufman – Regarding whey protein and Splenda (sucralose) I agree the research is quite sketchy.  Also things like who’s funding the study?  Are they financially tied to the sale of X product?  I also agree eating real food is better than supplements - except around workouts - I couldn’t find any studies comparing whey to other food based forms of protein, have you been able to find any?

Comment: @Mike-DHSc I'm not aware of anything that did control groups of different forms of protein while training, that would actually be pretty terrific but I imagine difficult and costly. Still, if we had results every six months for a couple of years with health tracking on top of it, that would cool. I do now that whey protein is prescribed for folks with some medical conditions (like missing portions of your intestine, or post bariatric surgery) so other-than-fitness-folks are getting advised to take it.

Comment: @EricKaufman Your [“mayoclinic.org” link](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements-whey-protein/art-20363344) says the following: “While some evidence suggests that taking whey protein as part of a strength training program increases muscle mass and strength, other studies show no benefits.” Doesn’t the whole question more or less hinge on this fact, which makes or breakes the effect that is sought?

Comment: @caw I don't think whey itself is magic beans, and while there are some studies showing it's a very good protein source I don't think that means something like chicken isn't, or doesn't have its own benefits. I answered this by really advocating for real food, whey currently is the safest/cheapest/cost-effective substitute if you can't get a high protein yield from actual food.

Comment: @EricKaufman Thanks! I know, and I agree. But I wasn’t wondering whether whey may be better than other protein sources or even actual food. It’s just that, from my understanding of the article, the Mayo Clinic questions whether whey protein supplements have *any* effect at all when it comes to your training for size or strength. That would be a huge contradiction to the general wisdom, wouldn’t it? The only possible conclusions would be that (a) whey supplements have no effect and you have to resort to other supplements and actual food, or that (b) protein intake is generally irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

### Breakfast

- Oatmeal (Steel Cut Oats)
- Fats: *(Min-Mod)*
- Protein: ~20 grams
- Source of Barley*

> *Coats your small intestine, decreasing the Glycemic Index of foods       you eat throughout the day in half. *One Source:* [Sprouted Grain
>   Bread](https://www.foodforlife.com/about_us/ezekiel-49)

---

### Pre Workout

*30 to 45 minutes before your workout*

- Whey Protein **(~25-40g)**
- Complex Carbs **(~30-55g)**
- Low Glycemic, **Fiber** Based Foods
- Sprouted Grain Bread
- Yogurt / Raw Fruits etc.)
- Fats: *(Minimal)*

---

### Post Workout:

*Immediately after your workout*

- Whey Protein **(~25-40g)**
- **No** Fiber, High Glycemic Foods
- Simple Sugars - Fructose and Glucose *(Processed Foods)*
- Fats: *(Min-Mod)*
- White Bread
- Table Sugar
- Honey

---

### Rationale:

> ***Whey Protein*** as it's one of the fastest digesting proteins
>
> - Studies have shown increased hypertrophy (muscle growth) by stacking    these pre and post workout.
>
> ***Fructose***  as fructose has different carriers than glucose, delivery of protein and therefore recovery and muscle growth has shown
>   to increase when taken as part of a post workout drink.
>
> ***Sucrose*** - Simple sugars as your muscles are starving - refined sugars post workout spike your insulin allowing maximum delivery of
>   protein.

---

### Before Bed

- Carbs: *Low*
- Protein: ~20 grams *(Casein Protein Ideal i.e Glass of Milk, Greek Yogurt)* *
- Fats *(Highest)* **

*Casein is a Slow digesting protein 
**Vital to regenerating hormones

---

### Related Studies

> **PRE-POST supplementation demonstrated a greater increase in lean body mass and 1RM strength** in two of three assessments. The changes
>   in body composition were supported by a greater increase in CSA of the
>   type II fibers and contractile protein content. **PRE-POST
>   supplementation also resulted in higher muscle Cr and glycogen values
>   after the training program**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17095924

---

> "As suggested in several publications, a bolus of **15-20 g protein**
>   **(from skimmed milk or whey proteins) and carbohydrate (± 30 g
>   maltodextrine)** drinks is needed **immediately after stopping exercise** to
>   stimulate muscle protein and tendon collagen turnover within 1 hour."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22666780

---

> **We conclude that a small dose (10 g) of whey protein with carbohydrate (21 g) can stimulate a rise in MPS after resistance
>   exercise** in trained young men that would be supportive of a positive
>   net protein balance, which, over time, would lead to hypertrophy.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18059587

---

> "**Ingestion of 40g whey protein** following
>   whole-body resistance exercise **stimulates a greater myofibrillar protein synthesis (MPS)** response than
>   20g in young resistance-trained men."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27511985

---

> "**Protein ingestion before sleep** represents an effective dietary
>   strategy to augment muscle mass and strength gains during resistance
>   exercise training in young men."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25926415

---

> **Ingestion of an amino acid and/or carbohydrate solution during the
>   initial hours following a single bout of resistance exercise promotes
>   an acute increase in protein net balance** compared to the fasted state.
>   The precise mechanism involved has not been elucidated but seems
>   related to an increased availability of intracellular amino acids
>   and/or an increase in plasma insulin concentration. **As a practical
>   recommendation, therefore, postexercise feeding appears to be very
>   important.**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11098159

---

> **"In conclusion, whey protein supplementation enhances whole body anabolism**, and may improve acute recovery of exercise performance
>   after a strenuous bout of resistance exercise."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28696380

---

> "**A 20-g dose of whey protein is sufficient for the maximal
>   stimulation of myofibrillar protein synthesis (MPS)** in rested and
>   exercised muscle of ~80-kg resistance-trained, young men"

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24257722

---

> We conclude that **chronic postexercise consumption of milk promotes
>   greater hypertrophy** during the early stages of resistance training
>   in novice weightlifters

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17684208

---

> The results demonstrate that where **post-exercise liquid protein
>   ingestion may enhance the adaptive response of skeletal muscle**, this
>   may be possible **without affecting gross energy intake** relative to
>   consuming a low energy drink.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25049135

Comment: oh, btw Mike! post-workout  list says "No High Glycemic Food" but then "White Bread, Sugar, Honey" which are AFAIK high glycemic