# How to construct a compound movement workout including the Super sets?

Tags: strength-training, body-fat

I have been doing compound movement workout for like 3 months now, could see the results in overall strength, and fat loss, but how do I now include some super sets in that workout for looking toned? I am aiming for 10% Body fat(currently 18%).
For e.g. I currently on a schedule for 4 days a week doing compound movements like Squats, Deadlifts, Bench Press,Bent over row,Pullups, pushups, HIIT, Clean&Jerk, Shoulder press. Can i include some super set for isolation exercises like Triceps pushdown, Dumbell curl, Traps exercises,etc?

Comment: Edited my question, hope it is clear now, just wan to know how to add supersets of isolation in compound movements

Answer (score 2):

That's terrific that you've stuck to a good compound lifting program for three months, I think you'll see even more results in the next nine months as well. [Strength training increases your metabolism](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19117/7091), which goes a long way towards burning fat.

You really have three levers to play with for losing fat (and getting "toned"), none of which really has anything to do with supersets:

1. Calories in, calories out, and the nature of the food you eat. This will have the largest impact (by far). Basically you need to dial your calories and macros in tighter so you're not taking in so many calories.
2. Strength training. You're doing that already, but be careful because if you start to reduce your calories too much you can lose a bit of strength, and/or not progress as quickly.
3. Aerobic activity. Running, swimming, cycling, and other activities will consume more calories although people tend to have a habit of over-eating to compensate. Don't burn 300 calories and reward yourself with a 500 calorie meal.

I would advise you to do the following.

1. Use a [calorie calculator](https://www.cancer.org/healthy/eat-healthy-get-active/take-control-your-weight/calorie-counter-calculator.html) to get a rough idea of how many calories you actually need.
2. Follow [a good strength training program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) with proven results that won't get your hurt.
3. Use an app like [myfitnesspal](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/) (there are others, pick one you like) to track the calories of ***everything*** you eat for a week, and compare that with the calories you need to ingest. Since you're strength training, also [pay attention to your protein intake (3.3g per kilogram of body weight)](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/36539/7091).

Lastly, try to be active. Riding your bike or walking to the store versus driving, when done for years on end, can make a big difference. Have a generally active lifestyle which similar to the impacts of strength training on the metabolism, has long term impacts to your calorie consumption.

Comment: That so much makes sense. Calories=Checked,Protein=Check,Aerobic activities=Check. The thing I failed to get is good workout schedule, due to my busy schedule i get chance to go to gym 4 days a week.Could you suggest some particular schedule?